# database select issue

Tags: table, select

I am writting plugin where i have custom table.
I am trying to access one random row from last 5 rows from this custom table.

```
"SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id > MAX(id)-5 AND id < MAX(id)+1 ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 1";
```

but does not work. Any solution ?

UPDATE
problem sorted as;

```
$ofset = rand(0, 4);
 $read_link_data = "SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT $ofset,1";
```

it works but i suspect is not optimal

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 "   or you can add more restrictions to fetch from last 5 by time. Hope it help you a bit

Comment: thanks. i had mistake. now is corrected but still does not work.  i need to find the max id number and then create range from which single row will be selected. any clue what is wrong?

Comment: What you are getting when you run sql